# Jquery File-Upload Multipart sending of single file selections

Tags: jquery, file-upload, submit

The following code is trying to impose a bespoke set of requirements as explained below. I am using the

[Jquery File Upload widget here](http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/):

I am trying to restrict uploads to a file-set structure and send this file-set as a single Multipart HTTP upload to our server. I have managed to enforce this file-set through a bind to 'fileuploadchange' where a user is restricted to only adding certain file types to the uploads queue (in this case they can only upload 1 TXT file and 1 WAV file at a time, no other combinations are allowed). My problem is using a bind to 'fileuploadsubmit' to initiate the upload. If a user selects both the TXT and WAV files in a single selection instance it works fine, however if they select each file as single file selection instances then only the second file chosen is uploaded.

```
.bind('fileuploadsubmit', function (e, data) {
        if($(".template-upload").length == 2){
            if(sent > 3){
                alert("Upload processing in progress. To upload another File-Set, please reset the form.");
                return false;
            }else if(sent == 3){
                sent++;
                return false;
            }else{
                if((data.files.length == 2)&&(sent == 0)){//Both files selected at once and work fine.
                    all_data = data;
                    sent = 2;
                }
                
                if(sent == 0){//get 1st file from single file selection and add to Global all_data variable for submission
                    all_data = data;
                    sent++;
                    return false;
                }else if(sent == 1){//get 2nd file from single file selection and add to Global all_data variable for submission
                    all_data['files'].push(data['files'][0]);
                    all_data['context'].push(data['context'][0]);
                    all_data['paramName'].push(data['paramName'][0]);
                    sent++;
                }
                
                if(sent == 2){//Only send when 2 files have been prepared in Global all_data variable
                    $("#loader_response").html("UPLOADING....");
                    sent++;
                    var jqXHR = all_data.submit();
                }
            }
        }else{
            alert("Only a file-set can be uploaded." + file_set_message);
            return false;
        }
    })
```

Any help would be much appreciated on getting this to work as desired.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
Fixed the problem as follows:

```
              }else if(sent == 1){//get 2nd file from single file selection and add to Global all_data variable for submission
                data['files'].push(all_data['files'][0]);
                data['context'].push(all_data['context'][0]);
                data['paramName'].push(all_data['paramName'][0]);
                sent++;
              }
```

followed by a data.submit() not all_data.submit()

FURTHER EDIT:
The data.submit() change causes a JQuery "Too Much Recursion" error. Remove the submit call all together as it will be default called when the method correct ends.